# Difference between Authorized API Access and Simple API Access

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am using google map in my app that i am currently developing, when i export it and run it for the first time it works fine, then i uninstall it and then do any modifications i run it and see on my device because everytime i cant export it. But when i am done with al d modifications when i try to export and run it, it crashes the app.
So i went back to google console and i saw the "Create an OAuth 2.0 client Id", what is the use of creating this id.
And moreover what is authorized access?
Is my problem related to me using simple Api Access

Answer (score 1):

You must include your client ID in all API requests. Your client ID identifies you as a Google Maps API for Work customer and enables support and purchased quota for your application. Requests made without a client ID are not eligible for Google Maps API for Work benefits.

You can read about it more over [here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/auth)

Simple API access are API calls that do not access any private user data. Your application must authenticate itself as an application belonging to your Google Developers Console project.This is needed to measure project usage for accounting purposes.

Authorized API access (OAuth 2.0) are API calls that access private user data. Before you can call them, the user that has access to the private data must grant your application access. Therefore, your application must be authenticated, the user must grant access for your application, and the user must be authenticated in order to grant that access. All of this is accomplished with OAuth 2.0 and libraries written for it.

Comment: great thanks..but u havent mentioned anything about y is my app crashing when i try to open goole map